# Correct way to take absolute value of INT_MIN

Tags: c

I want to perform some arithmetic in unsigned, and need to take absolute value of negative int, something like

```
do_some_arithmetic_in_unsigned_mode(int some_signed_value)
{
   unsigned int magnitude;
   int negative;
   if(some_signed_value<0) {
       magnitude = 0 - some_signed_value;
       negative = 1;
    } else {
       magnitude = some_signed_value;
       negative = 0;
    }
   ...snip...
}
```

But INT_MIN might be problematic, 0 - INT_MIN is UB if performed in signed arithmetic.
What is a standard/robust/safe/efficient way to do this in C?

EDIT:

If we know we are in 2-complement, maybe implicit cast and explicit bit ops would be standard? if possible, I'd like to avoid this assumption.

```
do_some_arithmetic_in_unsigned_mode(int some_signed_value)
{
   unsigned int magnitude=some_signed_value;
   int negative=some_signed_value<0;
   if (negative) {
       magnitude = (~magnitude) + 1;
    }
   ...snip...
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Conversion from signed to unsigned is well-defined: You get the corresponding representative modulo 2<sup>*N*</sup>. Therefore, the following will give you the correct absolute value of `n`:

```
int n = /* ... */;

unsigned int abs_n = n < 0 ? UINT_MAX - ((unsigned int)(n)) + 1U
                           : (unsigned int)(n);
```

*Update:* As @aka.nice suggests, we can actually replace `UINT_MAX + 1U` by `0U`:

```
unsigned int abs_n = n < 0 ? -((unsigned int)(n))
                           : +((unsigned int)(n));
```

Comment: Oh, and in the purely theoretical case where `UINT_MAX == INT_MAX == -(INT_MIN+1)`, it is impossible to represent `|INT_MIN|` as an `unsigned int` anyway =)

Comment: @DanielFischer: is that case actually possible, given that `int` and `unsigned int` are required to have the same size and alignment requirements?

Comment: It is possible, `unsigned int` could have one more padding bit than `int`. I've never heard of an implementation where that's the case, but the standard doesn't guarantee that it never happens. (Unless I've overlooked something.)

Comment: @Daniel: 6.2.6.2/2: "if there are M value bits in the signed type and N in the unsigned type, then M <= N", so you're right. The normal case is that M == N - 1, the perverse case is M == N and the signed type has a strictly greater range than its corresponding unsigned type.

Comment: If I write abs_n = n<0 ? 0U - ((unsigned int)(n)) : ((unsigned int)(n)); is it equally well defined?

Comment: @aka.nice: I think you're right. In that case I'd actually just write `abs_n = n < 0 : -((unsigned int)(n)) : n`. Good point!

Comment: @aka.nice: I think so. For example you could statically assert `(unsigned)INT_MIN != 0`, which is the test of the "Daniel Fischer condition" -- whether or not the mathematical value of `|INT_MIN|` can be represented as `unsigned int`. If it can't then obviously your function is impossible to implement, you need to use a larger unsigned type to hold the absolute value of a signed integer.

Comment: Actually, my proposed test is wrong. It accounts for 2's complement implementations, but not 1s' complement or sign-magnitude, where `(unsigned)INT_MIN != 0` would be true even if the absolute value didn't fit. The "Fischer condition" is necessary and sufficient if you want your function to return `unsigned int`, but a correct test for it isn't quite that simple...

Comment: @DanielFischer Re [one more padding bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231560/correct-way-to-take-absolute-value-of-int-min/61237052#comment16391623_12231604), I had used that pre-C99 where `long/unsigned long` were 64-bit except the `unsigned long` had one padding bit.  Seems the processor did not have 64-bit _unsigned_ native `*,/` instructions, so they took the easy way out.

Answer (score 6):

In the negative case, take `some_signed_value+1`. Negate it (this is safe because it can't be `INT_MIN`). Convert to unsigned. Then add one;

Comment: I checked and gcc generate same code for 1U+(unsigned)(-(x+1)) and for -(unsigned)(x), something like (~magnitude)+1 but branchless, so both will be as efficient. Later one seems a bit less intention obscuring though.

Comment: @aka.nice: Yes, I just checked it too. `1+(unsigned)-(x+1)` is perhaps a bit obscure, but it does not bring in the value conversion of a negative signed quantity to unsigned; the cast is purely a change in type, not a change in value. In your version, some reasoning effort needs to go into assuring that the arithmetic does what's expected; the argument is not as simple as "the values are in a safe range at each step".

Comment: Yes, indeed your solution better fit my initial intention. Re-interpreting the negative x as a positive is intention obscuring for one closely reading the code, and require knowledge of standard conventions. But less attentive reader will immediately recognize a form of abs in -(unsigned)x...

Comment: Suggest adding code this this good answer:  something like `unsigned abs_u(int i) { return i < 0 ? -(i+1) + 1u : (unsigned) i; }`.

Answer (score 2):

You can always test for `>= -INT_MAX`, this is always well defined. The only case is interesting for you is if `INT_MIN < -INT_MAX` and that `some_signed_value == INT_MIN`. You'd have to test that case separately.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to perform some arithmetic in `unsigned`, and need to take absolute value of negative `int`, ...

To handle pedantic cases:

The `|SOME_INT_MIN|`<sup>1</sup> has some special cases:

**1. Non-two's complement**

Ones' complement and sign-magnitude are rarely seen these days.

`SOME_INT_MIN == -SOME_INT_MAX` and `some_abs(some_int)` is well defined.  This is the easy case.

```
#if INT_MIN == -INT_MAX
some_abs(x);  // use matching abs, labs, llabs, imaxabs
#endif
```

**2. `SOME_INT_MAX == SOME_UINT_MAX`, 2's complement**

C allows the max of the *signed* and *unsigned* version of an integer type to be the same.  This is rarely seen these days.

2 approaches:
1) use a wider integer type, if it exist.

```
#if -INTMAX_MAX <= SOME_INT_MIN
imaxabs((intmax_t)x)
#endif
```

2) Use wide(st) floating-point (FP) type.
Conversion to a wide FP will work for `SOME_INT_MIN` (2's complement) as that value is a -(power-of-2).   For other large negatives, the cast may lose precision for a wide integer and not so wide `long double`.  E.g. 64-bit `long long` and 64-bit `long double`.

```
fabsl(x);  // see restriction above.
```

**3. `SOME_INT_MAX < SOME_UINT_MAX`**

This is the common case well handle by [@Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12231604/2410359)'s answer.   The below also handles case 1.

```
x < 0 ? -((unsigned) x) : ((unsigned) x);
```

---

**Higher Level Alternative**

In cases when code is doing `.... + abs(x)`, a well defined alternative is to subtract the negative absolute value: `.... - nabs(x)`.  Or as in `abs(x) < 100`, use `nabs > -100`.

```
// This is always well defined.
int nabs(int x) {
  return (x < 0) x : -x;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `SOME_INT` implies `int`, `long`, `long long` or `intmax_t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 static unsigned absolute(int x)
 {
          if (INT_MIN == x) {
                  /* Avoid tricky arithmetic overflow possibilities */
                  return ((unsigned) -(INT_MIN + 1)) + 1U;
          } else if (x < 0) {
                  return -x;
          } else {
                  return x;
          }
 }
```

Comment: It sounds OK, but it's mostly @R answer with one more branch, or maybe just @Jens answer...