# C++ how to sort the values in an array based on magnitude?

Tags: c++, sorting

For instance I have an array:

```
array[5]  = {-3, 4, 5, 1, -2}
```

I am trying to sort it as `{1, -2, -3, 4, 5}`.

I tried doing *bubble sort* with abs value but that did not work.

Comment: BTW, why not use `std::sort` ?

Comment: Does that work with dynamic single arrays?

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue you had with the bubble sort?

Comment: Why is *array[3]* having 5 values?

Comment: @ugandanwarlord It works with `std::begin` and `std::end`.

Comment: can you show your effort?

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of ways to sort like that, and one of the most easiest, in fact, is to use, the [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function from `<algorithm>`... (Just remember to set up your compiler for **C++11 or above**)

***Create an advanced_absolute function (As pointed out in comments):***

```
constexpr auto min_abs(int x)
{
    return x < 0 ? signed(unsigned(-1)) - signed(unsigned(x) + 1U) : x;
}
```

***And sort:***

```
std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array), [](int const num1, int const num2) -> bool
{
    return (num1 == INT_MIN ? min_abs(num1) : std::abs(num1)) < (num2 == INT_MIN ? min_abs(num2) : std::abs(num2));
});
```

and include these at the top...

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator> // This is already included the <iostream> and other headers dependent on this header...
```

Comment: I think this sorts in descending order of magnitude, not ascending.

Comment: Your comparison does not follow strict weak ordering. You want `<`, not `<=`. You also need to include `<iterator>`.

Comment: I think that in this comparison the results for `{2, -2}` and `{-2, 2}` are different.

Comment: @Ruks I completely agree with you.

Comment: This incorrectly sorts `INT_MIN`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231560/correct-way-to-take-absolute-value-of-int-min

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define size 5

void swap(int *xp, int *yp) 
{ 
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
   int i, j; 
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)       
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
           if (abs(arr[j]) > abs(arr[j+1])) 
              swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); 
}

int main()
{
   int array[size] = {-3, 4, 5, 1, -2}; 
   bubbleSort(array, size);
   for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
   {
       printf("%d ", array[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

It can give you a better understanding of how things would work at fine grain level.

[Bubblesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) function in C is taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/)

Comment: Just a note, for small arrays, it doesn't matter which sort algorithm is used, but for large arrays, bubblesort is one of the least efficient sort algorithms.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, While you maybe right. But OP didn't ask about efficiency.

Comment: sure, no ding, that's why I made sure to include it as "Just a note". It wasn't so much for your benefit as it was for the questioner, in case that was not known.

Answer (score 0):

Following ruk's idea, but simplified:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator> 
#include <cstdlib> 
// ...
std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array), [](int const num1, int const num2)
{
    // Don't call std::abs(INT_MIN), just return the correct value directly.
    if (num1==INT_MIN) return false; // First, because INT_MIN<INT_MIN==false 
    if (num2==INT_MIN) return true;
    // If we get here, neither value is INT_MIN so we can safely call std::abs
    return (std::abs(num1) < std::abs(num2));
});
```