# Should I use x = -x, to convert a negative number to a positive number and vice versa (in C++)?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if I should use this "x = -x" to convert a negative number to a positive number or a positive number to a negative number in C++. I mean is working pretty well so far, but I'm not sure if is recommended or not.

I would appreciate some feedback about this thing. Thanks!!

```
int x = 10;
if (x > 0) {
    x = -x;
}
cout << x; // x = -10;
```

Comment: Why do you need specific feedback on this? If it's working fine, then it's fine. There's only so many so many ways to turn a positive number into a negative one!

Comment: Seems about right. What other option(s) were you considering?

Comment: That's opinion-based. You could use something like `-std::abs(x)` which is a more verbose way of writing the shown code.

Comment: c++ compilers are really clever these days; therefore it's best just to write code the obvious (and most easily readable/understandable) way and let the compiler deal with translating that into the most efficient assembly code behind the scenes.  Unless you are an expert with decades of experience, it understands the CPU hardware better than you do, and can  therefore make better decisions about what will work best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine to do it that way. You shouldn't have to worry about something like that. If you're worried about performance, you should either mesure performance or check what assembly it generates.

I've created a [compiler explorer example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOXUYBVAM7YACgA8QAcgAMM8gCse5dq3qhUAUgBMAIT37yYzqiIEG1bPUwBhdOwCuAW3ohd5G5gAyBetgAcq4ARtikIACs5AAO6CLElvQOzm6qcQkWDH4BwS5hEdwm2GZZ9ExErKREKa7unqbY5kkVVUQ5QaHhUSaV1bVpRSJ97f6d%2Bd3cAJQm6E6kqFwy/kQA1C6s/hBTq9oA7IZyAIKrp6srq6y7AMwAIqvcctrXhydnV8/3ALSsz69nq1I2CI83olz%2B2mO%2B1uMhm7FkkUU7nkinQsjsRiMqxEcwW2F2umu3EURFkCimMwA1iBrtcAHS0xlM5lqWS8RQuKJycjIhTkNEyRQiEDc0komZwWAoDA4fDEMiUaiCZhsTg8fjK0QSaQo5QeNQaLSYgzFUpJay2AbubjXLy2Dp5Ao02LxRIMK08W0ZN30B1dCK2xrNBitfqOOqe01NMqh0a5f3O4ZtD023ptP0TAMzHHzRayC4bLY7fb/M4XD53B5PF6Qt6nK4AKk%2Bqy%2B3AhxwBQJBpDBvxrUL2MLhCKRZNR6ON%2BmxuMWBOuuhJY4p5CQ2FYOAi21ZMnZ5E5kW5vPHgpMIvIYvJVJAvAAnHSbw/H0%2Bn9vrqPdQLF%2BLyJKEPAINK6AuDEBCcBQVAQBgwGgd0wDcPBAigUQ4TChAIRjuQIT%2BFUACesjEuQUEuDYRAAPL0OweG6jgGyaGq1EEECzQAG7YMKurYJITROMhGErCUGHsAQISkLhDg4BhRCkAQnIyMSMzKiwHBcHwAgMEQWpSBhKhFOomhoJOajCcKkAzOgMRlOxQolNG5oQN4KZ2r4YyOpMLqZEkjnemUGZOkMNnBuUIyOUGMYjL5blJmGqTWmm1QRYU2Yzipw4yIiPIYQKkgABwAGxfLlvCrMAqCoA83B0twqwQHKJCkHORSrA40FgQ1OwYgYRhfpe5DUge267vuh6ZbIQpnhesI/ogAFoEBIFgYqkFzTBERwQhNBISh1DobqWH0Lh%2BGKERJHkZRGE0Ya9F8oQTEWKx7F8px3G8XJij8fCupCSJYlYEsfJSTJh0KepSlqqpmpiFpuoqJ4elGp1JpfSZW7mZZo1RoFFr2OGgxOQl6SumUXmE0k%2BP%2BWaIbBTjsWhS04UuQmQxUzFqhRXG4x%2BUluZcLoqXpUe/KyDl%2BWFcVpXlZV1W1WQc6eE1y2tXo87tZO3WwjMq7rt0W7Uo83IfYNXIZR%2B6PCqKS5Xre97PjbD6vu%2BfKfueFvbguxuO%2BjE3LqxpAJFYvBAA%3D). It compares the assembly for both `x = - x;` and `x *= -1;`. You can clearly see, even if you don't know assembly, that it generates the same code. And not very much of it anyway! (And it goes away when optimiser flags are on.

Comment: I've delibaretely ignored "low level" ways of doing negative numbers. But maybe there's another common way of doing it that I've missed or forgotten about?

Comment: How does your code handle: `int x = INT_MIN;` and then: `x = -x;` ?? ‎

Comment: @AdrianMole it probably doesn't work no matter what code you use.  How often would that situation come up, and what could you do to fix it?

Comment: Tried it in compiler explorer^^ Didn't think about that behaviour, but I don't think it was the point of the question. I'm getting "-2147483648" is that the intended behaviour? (Using std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), if it makes any difference).

Comment: But then that's undefined behaviour, so it's working fine, no? ^^

Comment: @Mark I was just being mischievous. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12231560/10871073)

Comment: @MarkRansom `it probably doesn't work no matter what code you use.` You can at least achieve error handling instead of the undefined behaviour.